# How to pass a variable between two view in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

As you see in the tile I try to share a variable between two views (the id of the selected object).
How can I do?

Here is my code for put on my other view :

```
EditProd *edit = [[EditProd alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditProd" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];        
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:edit animated:YES];
[edit release];
```

And which code I need in my other view  to get this variable?

Comment: You should provide some context on what exactly you're wanting to share. For instance, are you trying to share from the view controller this code is in, or are you trying to just access a variable from `EditProd` in this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EditProd should have a public property e.g.

```
 @property bool myBooleanVariable;
```

Then just change it from view1 e.g.

```
EditProd *edit = [[EditProd alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditProd" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];        
edit.myBooleanVariable = false;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:edit animated:YES];
[edit release];
```

Comment: Forgot to say: if you want EditProd to update view1's variable when finished you will have to look into Delegate.

Answer (score 1):

[Declare a property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) on your second view controller (EditProd), and then set that property before calling pushViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it three different ways:

- add a property to the new view and write to it from the first view
- add protocol with method, that can take this variable, set the delegate to the first view, access from new view
- save variable into some object, which is accessible from both views